# Sorting problems with charts in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, charts

I'm using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart() to create a chart png file. I have the following code:

```
string t = @"<Chart> 
            <ChartAreas> 
                <ChartArea Name=""Default"" _Template_=""All""> 
                    <AxisX Interval=""1""></AxisX> 
                </ChartArea> 
            </ChartAreas> 
        </Chart>";

var chart = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart()
{
    Size = new Size(x, y),
    Titles = { chartName },
};

var series = new Series("Savings");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.Points.DataBindXY(preparedGraphCollection.Keys, preparedGraphCollection.Values);                

chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;                

chart.Series.Add(series);                

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(graphTempFilePath);
chart.SaveImage(graphTempFilePath + filename + ".png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

preparedGraphCollection contains a KayValuePair list, where the keys represent week numbers and the values is an incrementing number for each week, like so

```
50 => 310
51 => 335
52 => 340
1 => 350
2 => 375
```

My problem is that even though i havent sent any sorting or so in the chart, the chart comes out where the week numbers are sorted in a way so that the smallest number is plotted in first. This gives a wierd looking chart. Even though the keys and values are not sorted this way, the Chart is created with that kind of sorting. To show it like above, its like the chart has recieved the data like so:

```
1 => 350
2 => 375
50 => 310
51 => 335
52 => 340
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Since your x-values are numbers they are added in place. To make them show in the order you add them, you can either set `Series.IsXValueIndexed = true` or add them as DateTime and set the individual Labels to the week numbers..

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what i needed. I went with your suggestion about setting `Series.IsXValueIndexed = true`. Would you like to provide your comment here as an answer, so that i can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your x-values are **numbers** they are added **in place**.

To make them show in the order you add them instead, you can

- **either** set `Series.IsXValueIndexed = true`
- **or** add them as `DateTime` and set the individual `Labels` to the week numbers.
- **Or** you could add them add strings.

A few notes:

- The former is really simple but will not create proportional spacing. As you probably don't want/need that, I suggest setting the series to be indexed.
- The second option is tricky as week numbers do not easily convert to the correct dates.
- Adding x-values as strings is **not** recommended as it will **lose** the actual values! (Even though the labels will still look ok..)

`IsXValueIndexed` is also often used to avoid gaps in the data like weekends etc..

Note that now **all** other `Series` in the same `ChartArea` must also be indexed.